# generate cmake debug files for isolated catkin workspace

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, cmake, catkin-make-isolated, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have a problem while trying to use eclipse to debug ros c++ projects in an isolated catkin workspace.
In this workspace I have several packages, that I build with:

```
catkin_make_isolated --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"
```

However, in order to debug, I have to create the corresponding tracing files that typically would have to be created by going to the "catkin_ws/build" directoy and using

```
cmake ../src -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

Unfortunately, if I try to use this in the build folder for the isolated catkin workspace  "catkin_ws/build_isolated/", I get the error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:95 (message):
  This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build
  a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation.  Try the
  'catkin_make_isolated' command instead.
```

Without building these debug files, I get  the following eclipse error while debugging:

```
No source available for main
```

Do you have any idea where and how to get these cmake debug files?
Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318394/generate-cmake-debug-files-for-isolated-catkin-workspace/) by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2019-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can pass the build type directly by calling

```
catkin_make_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1